# Is it possible to add an inline description to an AWS Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket policy in AWS to control access via IP, [as per their standard examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html), & would like to be able to add a comment or description inline (in the interest of keeping documentation as close to the implementation as possible).

If I try to add a custom field, e.g. `Description`, I'll get a validation error on save — *"Invalid policy element - Description"*.

I can [find this reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies-grammar.html) to the grammar of required elements, but can't seem to find any info on whether there are any optional fields allowed at all by the schema, & if so what they are.

Is it possible to add any fields to give an overview of the policy inline?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"},
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.188/32"} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page you cited, `Sid` is probably what you want to use for this.  It's largely freeform, but you probably want to use underscores where you might otherwise use spaces.

> **sid_string**
>
> Provides a way to include information about an individual statement. Some services require this value to be unique within an AWS account. Some services allow spaces in the Sid value, and others do not.

```
"Sid": "ThisStatementProvidesPermissionsForConsoleAccess"
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that in the middle of it all

Comment: Seems that S3 bucket policies do allow spaces, though other managed policies do not.